# why comparing null function pointer results in "invalid operands to binary =="

Tags: c

Can somebody please explain to me why the below code got the "invalid operands to binary ==" error?

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int);
#define NO_FUNC ((func_t) 0)
struct {
    const char *name;
    func_t func;
} table[] = { {"func1", NO_FUNC} };

if (table[0] == NO_FUNC) { // invalid operands to binary ==

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `table[0].func == NO_FUNC`?

Comment: @millimoose That's what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And you should refer to the correct member in the struct:

```
if (table[0].func == NO_FUNC)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have noticed the mistake and edited it a minute ago.

Answer (score 2):

`table[0]` is of an unnamed `struct` type, and `NO_FUNC` has type `int (*)(int)`.  These two types can't be compared.

Instead, you could use:

```
if (table[0].func == NO_FUNC)
```